# getting data from 2 tables in inner join

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I am  not new in inner join but i don't know why i am getting data from two tables

Look i have some tables

Table One

```
select TransactionMId,ModelNumber,EmeiNo,Color from tblTransactionD
```

> TransactionMId    ModelNumber EmeiNo  Color
>
> c174f2c0-72f4-4746-b83d-21ffca6a5a61  620G    10001   grey
>
> c174f2c0-72f4-4746-b83d-21ffca6a5a61  ONE 10005   black
>
> 4fa11531-886a-4d15-af5c-7355cc3648f5  620G    10001   grey

Table Two

```
select TransactionMId,ModelNumber,EmeiNo,Color from tblTransactionP
```

> TransactionMId    ModelNumber EmeiNo  Color
>
> c174f2c0-72f4-4746-b83d-21ffca6a5a61  620G    10001   grey
>
> c174f2c0-72f4-4746-b83d-21ffca6a5a61  ONE 10005   black

table three

```
select TransactionMId,ModelNumber,EmeiNo,Color from tblTransactionS
```

> TransactionMId    ModelNumber EmeiNo  Color
>
> 4fa11531-886a-4d15-af5c-7355cc3648f5  620G    10001   grey

now i want to show the data which is in table one and two but not in table three

Here is my Inner Join

```
SELECT TD.BrandId,TD.Color,TD.EmeiNo FROM dbo.tblTransactionD AS TD
INNER JOIN dbo.tblTransactionP AS TP
ON
TP.transactionMId=TD.transactionMId
INNER JOIN dbo.tblTransactionS AS TS
ON
TP.EmeiNo != TS.EmeiNo
```

but the executed result is showing data like this

```
BrandId Color   EmeiNo
1   grey    10001
1   black   10005
```

the record of 10001 should not be shown in the query because it is in table three

what is wrong in my inner join

Comment: 10005 is different than 10001, so the condition (TP.EmeiNo != TS.EmeiNo) is valid when checking the records related to 10005... according to the data and query, the result is what correct :-P

Comment: what Database are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

Following query will work:

```
SELECT TD.BrandId,TD.Color,TD.EmeiNo FROM dbo.tblTransactionD AS TD
INNER JOIN dbo.tblTransactionP AS TP
ON
TP.transactionMId=TD.transactionMId
where TP.EmeiNo not in (select distinct EmeiNo from dbo.tblTransactionS);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can try like this;

```
SELECT TD.BrandId,TD.Color,TD.EmeiNo FROM dbo.tblTransactionD AS TD
INNER JOIN dbo.tblTransactionP AS TP
ON TP.transactionMId=TD.transactionMId
where TP.EmeiNo not in (select distinct EmeiNo from dbo.tblTransactionS);
```

As your description **tblTransactionS** (three table) join **is not necessary.**

Comment: Output doesn't show 10001 as it's in table 3. So, yeah no need to join 3rd table but where condition is required to eliminate `EmeiNo` which is there in 3rd table. Hence,above query won't work.